can't generate the speech from library tts of coqui-tts and this error happens in single and multi speakers
from TTS.utils.manage import ModelManager
from TTS.utils.synthesizer import Synthesizer

from google.colab import files

Initialize the model manager and load the models

model_name = "tts_models/en/ljspeech/tacotron2-DDC"

vocoder_name = "vocoder_models/en/ljspeech/hifigan_v2"

model_manager = ModelManager()

model_path, config_path, _ = model_manager.download_model(model_name)

vocoder_path, vocoder_config_path, _ = model_manager.download_model(vocoder_name)

Create the synthesizer object

synthesizer = Synthesizer(model_path, config_path, vocoder_path, vocoder_config_path, use_cuda=False)

Generate dynamic SSML based on manually chosen emotion

def generate_dynamic_ssml(chunk):

ssml = f"""<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'>"""  



# Uncomment the emotion you want to apply

ssml += f"<prosody pitch='+10%' rate='fast'><emphasis level='moderate'>{chunk}</emphasis></prosody>"  # happy

# ssml += f"<prosody pitch='+5%' rate='medium'><emphasis level='strong'>{chunk}</emphasis></prosody>"  # romantic

# ssml += f"<prosody pitch='+7%' rate='medium'><emphasis level='moderate'>{chunk}</emphasis></prosody>"  # hopeful

# ssml += f"<prosody pitch='default' rate='medium'><emphasis level='none'>{chunk}</emphasis></prosody>"  # neutral

# ssml += f"<prosody pitch='-5%' rate='slow'><emphasis level='moderate'>{chunk}</emphasis></prosody>"  # disappointed

# ssml += f"<prosody pitch='-10%' rate='fast'><emphasis level='strong'>{chunk}</emphasis></prosody>"  # angry

# ssml += f"<prosody pitch='-10%' rate='slow'><emphasis level='strong'>{chunk}</emphasis></prosody>"  # fearful

# ssml += f"<prosody pitch='-15%' rate='slow'><emphasis level='strong'>{chunk}</emphasis></prosody>"  # sad

# ssml += f"<prosody pitch='-20%' rate='very slow'><emphasis level='strong'>{chunk}</emphasis></prosody>"  # devastated



ssml += "</speak>"  

return ssml  

Function to synthesize speech for each chunk

def synthesize_speech(text):

# Generate SSML for the whole text with a manually selected emotion  

ssml = generate_dynamic_ssml(text)  



# Synthesize the text  

wav = synthesizer.tts(ssml)  



# Save the output file  

output_file = "output_with_emotion.wav"  

synthesizer.save_wav(wav, output_file)  



# Download the file to the local machine  

files.download(output_file)  

Example usage

if name == "main":

sample_text = """I am so happy to see you! You make my heart race with joy and love.""" 

 

# Convert text to speech with the selected emotion 

synthesize_speech(sample_text)

code using tacotron2 model and vocoder hifigen after that I use the synthesizer library ssml that change the pitch of the voice to make it like emotion
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-8-2698293d91f3> in <cell line: 51>()

 53  

 54     # Convert text to speech with the selected emotion 

---> 55     synthesize_speech(sample_text)

1 frames

<ipython-input-8-2698293d91f3> in synthesize_speech(text)

 39  

 40     # Synthesize the text 

---> 41     wav = synthesizer.tts(ssml)

 42  

 43     # Save the output file 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/TTS/utils/synthesizer.py in tts(self, text, speaker_name, language_name, speaker_wav, style_wav, style_text, reference_wav, reference_speaker_name, split_sentences, **kwargs)

320                     speaker_id = self.tts_model.speaker_manager.name_to_id[speaker_name] 

321             # handle Neon models with single speaker. 

--> 322             elif len(self.tts_model.speaker_manager.name_to_id) == 1:

323                 speaker_id = list(self.tts_model.speaker_manager.name_to_id.values())[0] 

324             elif not speaker_name and not speaker_wav: 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name_to_id' that is the error


that tts code using coqui-tts that make emotional tts so the following error always apper and I have tried to make the code single and multi speakers
make single and multi speakers maybe someone know the solution or advice me to use another model I want it a free one
